# Eclipse responds very slow if i am editing any .robot file

Tags: eclipse, frameworks, robotframework, eclipse-oxygen

When I type some thing in .robot file, Eclipse is lagging in entering that into the file.
If I type a word now, it was taking 5mins to enter.

Its happening only with the Robot file, I am able to do it properly with the other files like java, py....

I tried the below thing
1) Increasing the RAM size in eclipse.ini
2) Tried removing the auto suggestion
3) Created a new work-space and imported into the project
4) Tried by downloading the new Eclipse (Oxygen)

nothing made my problem resolve.

Comment: What editor is being use for the .robot files? This is most likely an issue with the specific editor

Comment: I am using RED Editor, till yesterday I am able to work properly. Suddenly I am facing this issue.

Comment: If you right-click the file and choose _Open With > Text Editor_ you don't have the issue, right?

Comment: Yes I am not facing any issue there

Comment: So it's not Eclipse as the title claims. If you have this issue in the latest version of the [RED - Robot Editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/red-robot-editor) plug-in, [report it to the RED - Robot Editor developers](https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues), if it hasn't been reported yet.

Comment: Ok, but how can we say it as an issue? Because I am able to work with that previously.

Comment: I figured it out, the issue is similar to [this](https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues/259), but that is closed. I will post a comment there. Thanks @howlger

Comment: @King The issue is not closed, it only references a closed issue. Closed or not, leave a comment that you are facing this issue, too. Maybe you can give more information to reproduce this issue to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pycharm**

please refer this link  [configuring pycharm to run Robot framework tests](https:////blog.bigbinary.com/2015/10/11/configuring-pycharm-to-run-tests.html)